# Excel formula if statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a formula in Excel that does the following.
I want the value of a cell to be equal to A,B,C or D based on this criteria: 
if Cell is > 0, value is A;

if Cell is between 0 to -2, value is B;

if Cell is between -3 to -5, value is C;

if Cell is between -11 to -30, value is D;

if Cell is more than -30, value is E.

Comment: We can't/won't write your code for you, and certainly can't interpret something like this. Please edit your question so that it's more clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want the value of a cell to be equal to A,B,C or D based on this criteria:
if Cell is > 0, value is A; if Cell is between 0 to -2, value is B; if Cell is between -3 to -5, value is C, if Cell is between -11 to -30, value is D, if Cell is more than -30, value is E.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38232336/680068).

Answer (score 0):

Sourced from [PC World](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2971613/software-productivity/excel-logical-formulas-5-simple-if-statements-to-get-started.html)

Where B4 is the cell target, substitute your cell values in there. Here's an example using other values. Adjust as needed.

`=IF(B4>89,”A”,IF(B4>79,”B”,IF(B4>69,”C”,IF(B4>59,”D”,”F”))))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this formular:

```
=IF(AND(-30<= A1, A1<=-11), "D", IF(AND(-10<= A1, A1<=-6), "C", IF(AND(-5<= A1, A1<=-3), "B", IF(AND(-2<= A1, A1<=0), "A", IF(A1>0, "Overdue", "-")))))
```

Output:

A1  Result:

---

-8  C

-7  C

-6  C

-5  B

-4  B

-3  B

-2  A

-1  A

0   A

1   Overdue

2   Overdue

3   Overdue

4   Overdue

[image]